# Is checking for a null text field bad for performance?

Tags: mysql

I have a game service, some of my "gamerooms" are password protected. In the public listing of games, I'd only like to fetch games which do not have a password. My table looks like:

```
id | gameName | date | password | 
---------------------------------
 1   foo        123    null
 2   grok       456    abc
 ...
```

So I'm wondering if it's ok performance-wise to do the following to find public games:

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE password != null ORDER BY date LIMIT 50;
```

(I don't know the syntax for the != null part) but figuring something like that exists, is that going to be bad performance-wise? Should I instead add an additional column named "isPublic" which is just a small int, with values { 0, 1 } for { false, true }? Then I could do:

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE isPublic = 1 ORDER BY date LIMIT 50;
```

and I guess I'd have to put an index on "isPublic" to get the best performance out of it?

Totally wrong on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably be fine with:

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE password IS NULL ORDER BY date LIMIT 50;
```

In fact, MySQL is optimized for using NULL as just a normal value: http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/MySQL-Optimization-part-1/4/

The only problem I see with that is that the semantics get a little bit hidden, but as for performance, you would probably do well doing a little benchmark for this particular issue.

Comment: +1: Correct - `!=` is for actual value comparison.  To compare against NULL, you need to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

No, null is an absolutely first order value in SQL DBs.  There is no reason that you should get any type of performance hit.

That being said, it would be trivial and instructive to do a test, so that is my suggestion.

Comment: Ok - to test, I thought mysql query browser should you how long a query took (but don't see it anymore). I don't know if that's a good way to do it either, I can run it on live data, though. It all depends on my data I guess.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know MySQL doesn't support true `BOOLEAN`, it's just a `TINYINT(1)`. From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html:

> BOOL, BOOLEAN
>
> These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of zero is considered
>   false. Nonzero values are considered true.

So doing something like

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE isPublic = 'true'
```

would be the worst case, because you would be comparing strings. That being said, there's nothing wrong with `null`.